NUXT Environment variables available on server but not on client
I have a NUXT app that reads from a separate API. I need to change this API URL for different environments.
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {     
    public: {
      apiUrl: "https://prod-url.com/api"
    }
  }
})


I try to send in the API URL using envvars
NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://local-url.com/api
The behavior is as follows.
On server:
console.log(process.env) logs:
NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://local-url.com/api
On client
const config = useRuntimeConfig(); console.log(config)

here is the config.public.apiUrl value is "https://prod-url.com/api"
So the value wont be overwritten by the env var.

One weird behavior is that sometimes the config.public.apiUrl is updated. But this is never on the initial load, but sometimes on a refresh or opening of a new tab.

If I am not mistaken, the "https://prod-url.com/api" in your config file is a safety net in case you do not have the variable defined aka a static default. Give watch to the video in that answer to have more details regarding the variables. Also, consider not using console.log on the client but rather inspecting the state somewhere in the template or in your Vue devtools. console.log might be a bit tricky sometimes in terms of context, async etc. Also, what do you have if you check the value of useRuntimeConfig.apiUrl on the client?

The value is missing in my frontend, as my api calls are not working. But as I mentioned in the question, after a refresh, or mostly opening of a new tab the API calls are working and using the correct URL.
But at initial load of the app after restart of the app, the envvars are always missing.

When you open a new tab, you go to the server again hence not making a client-side but a server one. This is coming back to your findings already mostly. Hence why I propose something different that you could try. I am not sure why your client-side does not have the proper value but again, please give a read to the linked answer.

So far, it works perfectly on my side. Some more context or a [repro] would be helpful here because I cannot guess what is wrong with your setup. Try maybe starting a new project just to double-check how the env variables work there.
